# Generate vue components from a nested object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dictionary

Is there any good way to use a nested object to generate vue components?

I have a deeply nested object that looks like this:

```
"api": {
  "v1": {
    "groups": {
       "create": true,
       "get": true,
       "item": {
          "get": true,
          "destroy": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to generate a form which has checkboxes for each of the values of the object.
I'm having trouble binding the values of the object to the v-models in a Vue checkbox

I've tried making a list of lookup keys like ["api.v1.groups.create", "api.v1.groups.get"]
then using a function like the following to get the entries:

```
getPerm (p) {
  return p.split('.').reduce(
    (xs, x) => (xs && xs[x]) ? xs[x] : null,
    this.role.permissions)
}
```

However, this does not work because it gives me the boolean and not the reference.

Comment: Woah I got stuck on this same problem yesterday! 

I ended up using recursion, but it assumes all keys with values are unique, which isn't the case here.

Comment: Actually sorry I just re-read this and think we may have different issues.  You're trying to find references inside the object for your vue components right? Is it possible to process the 'api' input before it makes it to your vue component?

Comment: @JesseRezaKhorasanee I'm essentially trying to do this: v-model="model.api.v1.groups.create" for each entry

Comment: Ah ok cool I think I get it now. Can we not just use `watch` to process our input into a separate object and point our v-models to that? I'm busy on something else at the moment but I'll try this out soon

Comment: I'm going to try the things you suggested and see it it'll work

Comment: I just tried putting out flattened object into a vue compoenents `data` and it works! [Check it out here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-basic-example-yviml?file=/src/components/Chart.component.vue)

Answer (score 0):

Check out my:
[Code sandbox to flatten dict and create a list from a nested entry](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-basic-example-yviml?file=/src/components/Chart.component.vue)

*( I forked it from a basic Vue template so it still has some references to 'chart' in there)*

Once you have flattened the dictionary you use them to generate vue components using `v-for` as you normally would!

Below is the processing I used to flatten the dictionary if you would like to check that here on site:

```js
// Define out nested object
var nested = {
  "api": {
    "v1": {
      "groups": {
        "create": true,
        "get": true,
        "item": {
          "get": true,
          "destroy": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// function for checking if we are at the bottom of the Object
const isObj = o => o?.constructor === Object;

// I had to use a class to store the output in the different recursive scopes
class NestedProcessor {
  // Constructur starts the function and returns the dictionary as flat
  constructor(leveled_dict) {
    this.output = {}
    this.process_dict_recursive(leveled_dict)
    return this.ouput
  }
  process_dict_recursive(leveled_dict, keyList = [], depth = 0) {
    if (isObj(leveled_dict)) { // check if we have hit the bottom
      keyList.push('')
      depth++ 
      for (let key in leveled_dict) { 
        keyList[depth - 1] = key
        this.process_dict_recursive(leveled_dict[key], keyList, depth) // call the function recursively at our new depth
      }
    }
    else {
      // Create our lookup keys
      let path = ''
      keyList.forEach((v) => {
        path += v
        path += '.'
      })
      path = path.slice(0, -1) // Remove the last '.'
      this.output[path] = leveled_dict
    }
  }
}

console.log(new NestedProcessor(nested))
//{
//  "output": {
//    "api.v1.groups.create": true,
//    "api.v1.groups.get": true,
//    "api.v1.groups.item.get": true,
//    "api.v1.groups.item.destroy": false
//  }
//}
```

**Notes:**

- I used a class, because I couldn't figure out how to handle variable scope within the recursion
- I needed a way to check if we were at the bottom so grabbed a function from SO to check for that.